# How erase part of a text in JS?

Tags: javascript, text

I have this in javascript:

```
let text1 = 'Hello World by artist XXXX';
let text2 = 'Bye World by artist YYYY';
let text3 = '¿World? by artist ZZZZ';
```

I need to keep the text before "by artist XXXX" in another variable. Like this:

```
let keepText1 = 'Hello World';
let keepText2 = 'Bye World';
let keepText3 = '¿World?';
```

Is there a way to do it?

And How can I erase a phrase after the text "by" ?? I mean, what if the artist have a different name like:

```
let text4 = 'Hello Universe by artist Daniel Zamoga';
```

I need:

```
let keepText4 = 'Hello Universe';
```

Comment: Have you looked at `String.prototype.indexOf` and `String.prototype.substring` or `String.prototype.replace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex replace `.replace(/ by artist [A-Z]+/, '')`

```js
console.log('Hello World by artist XXXX'.replace(/ by artist [A-Z]+/, ''));
console.log('Bye World by artist YYYY'.replace(/ by artist [A-Z]+/, ''));
console.log('¿World? by artist ZZZZ'.replace(/ by artist [A-Z]+/, ''));
```

Comment: It may be better to use `(.*)` for matching the artist name, because it could contain multiple words and numbers. E.g. `Blink 182`, `Michael Jackson`, etc.

Comment: I am not too concerned about the exact regex, I just gave a demo that works for the provided sample texts.

Answer (score 0):

you could split and take first part:

```
"Hello World by artist XXXX".split(" by artist")[0]
```

would return `"Hello World"`